# How to save ListView selected item

Tags: c#, listview

I'm trying to save a `ListView` selected item and I don't know why I'm getting this error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection'"

I tried this code on the save button:

```
Settings.Default["SelectedDevice"] = sourceList.SelectedItems; //Works fine
```

on Form_Load I tried this:

```
sourceList.SelectedItems = (int)Settings.Default["SelectedDevice"]; //error
```

Comment: Why do you try to cast the SelectedListViewItemCollection to int?

Comment: this isn't working neither: sourceList.SelectedItems = Settings.Default["SelectedItem"];

Comment: what are you trying to do? save a default value to be selected when the form is loaded?

Comment: you save it as "SelectedItem" but again read it as "SelectedDevice"! typo?

Comment: I fixed it , but the error is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a small application where I read the selecteditem from the settings. The code to select the Item in the OnLoad-Event is:

```
 private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
 {
    int selectedItem = Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedItem;
    if (selectedItem != -1)
    {
       this.listView1.Items[selectedItem].Selected = true;
    }
  }
```

The Default-Value of my Settings is -1

Answer (score 0):

First of all `SelectedItems` is a **readonly** property, it can't be set. Secondly it's a `SelectedListViewItemCollection` not an `int`.

If you are trying to store the selected *indices* of items in your list you would need to do something along the lines of:

```
// store CSV list of indices
Settings.Default["SelectedItems"] = String.Join(",", listView.SelectedIndices.Select(x => x));
...
// load selected indices
var selectedIndices = ((string)Settings.Default["SelectedItems]).Split(',');
foreach (var index in selectedIndices)
{
    listView.Items[Int32.Parse(index)].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: So no way to save it ?

Comment: I tried this and it not working : sourceList.SelectedItems = Settings.Default["SelectedDevice"];

Comment: @ORION Like I said that codes never going to work because `SelectedItems` is **read only**. See my update for a more reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
sourceList.SelectedItems = (int)Settings.Default["SelectedDevice"]; //error
```

There is your error.

Please refer to the following.
[How to select an item in a ListView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791235/how-to-select-an-item-in-a-listview-programmatically)